# linux-generic not installed in fresh installation

Tags: metapackages

In a fresh installation of **Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS** I noticed, that autoremove suggests to remove `linux-image-generic` and also that `linux-generic` is not installed at all.

Is that a bug or did the management of kernel images change?

Answer (score 0):

On a fresh installation from the 14.04.1 iso, the package linux-generic 3.13.0.32.38 should have been installed.

You can observe what related packages are installed using this (and my example is **NOT** from the fresh not upgraded installation):

```
doug@s15:~/docs-1404/tt_01/html$ dpkg -l | grep linux
ii  libselinux1:amd64                    2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1                      amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  linux-firmware                       1.127.11                              all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-firmware-image                 3.11.0-rc6-31                         amd64        Linux kernel firmware, version 3.11.0-rc6
ii  linux-firmware-image-3.19.0-rc1-250  3.19.0-rc1-250-181                    amd64        Linux kernel firmware, version 3.19.0-rc1-250
ii  linux-generic                        3.13.0.45.52                          amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-43              3.13.0-43.72                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-43-generic      3.13.0-43.72                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-44              3.13.0-44.73                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic      3.13.0-44.73                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-45              3.13.0-45.74                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic      3.13.0-45.74                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-rc5-250         3.19.0-rc5-250-189                    amd64        Linux kernel headers for 3.19.0-rc5-250 on amd64
ii  linux-headers-generic                3.13.0.45.52                          amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-server                 3.13.0.45.52                          amd64        Transitional package.
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic        3.13.0-43.72                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic        3.13.0-44.73                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic        3.13.0-45.74                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.19.0-rc5-250           3.19.0-rc5-250-189                    amd64        Linux kernel, version 3.19.0-rc5-250
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic  3.13.0-43.72                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic  3.13.0-44.73                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic  3.13.0-45.74                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                  3.13.0.45.52                          amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-server                   3.13.0.45.52                          amd64        Transitional package.
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                 3.13.0-45.74                          amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-server                         3.13.0.45.52                          amd64        Transitional package.
ii  util-linux                           2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.3                  amd64        Miscellaneous system utilities
```

Answer (score 0):

After initial fresh installation, was there a software update/upgrade?
Usually when the software update gets run, you get a suggestion to auto-remove older kernels.
So we can better answer your question, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Copy and paste the results here, it should look something like:

```
Generating grub.cfg
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic
```

and so on..... 
This will let us see exactly everything you've got installed.

Comment: 7bluehand: that wouldn't tell you about the linux-generic package. See the edit I just made to my answer.